# Set prompt text to the center of TextArea control in JavaFX

Tags: textarea, javafx-8

I was wondering if there is a way to set prompt text location in TextArea.

Basically I am trying to create the similar effect as ListView Placeholder does. It is just to keep consistency in UI, so that everything mostly would look similar.

Any suggestions with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do this by a dirty hack:
Set alignment to **center**.
Depending on your desired behavior either add a focus listener which sets the alignment to left again when focused and back to center when focus left.

```
text.focusedProperty().addListener((p,o,n)->{
  if(n){
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
  }else      {
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  }
});
```

Or add a keylistener to get the left aligned text while typing(and a focus-left listener to reset it if needed, eg. empty)

```
setOnKeyPressed(e->text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT));
```